# Distinct Values from DB query in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, database, model-view-controller

i am trying to create a button for each distinct value returned from my TRACK_INFO table.  The column I am trying to return is the collegeOf column.  Right now, I get a button for every row in my table instead of just the distinct ones.  Can somebody please help?  I am new to using asp.net mvc.  Below is my controller code that returned the rows from my TRACK_INFO table.

```
// GET: /Tracks/
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var track_info = db.TRACK_INFO.Include(t => t.GRAD_CLEAR_SIG_DATE);
    return View(track_info.ToList());
}
```

Comment: Use Distinct method of Linq to get the distinct values.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Linq Distinct method with a custom EqualityComparer (I'm assuming in the example that  collegeOf is a string):

```
public class TrackInfoComparer : IEqualityComparer<TRACK_INFO>
{
    public bool Equals(TRACK_INFO x, TRACK_INFO y)
    {
        if (x.collegeOf == y.collegeOf) //etc...
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Usuers obj)
    {
        return obj.IdUser.GetHashCode();
    }
```

}

Allowing you to filter the distinct records:

```
var track_info = db.TRACK_INFO.Include(t => t.GRAD_CLEAR_SIG_DATE).Distinct(new TrackInfoComparer);
return View(track_info.ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `GroupBy` to get the Distinct items from the list.

**Code:**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var track_info = db.TRACK_INFO.Include(t => t.GRAD_CLEAR_SIG_DATE);

    //Check the below code
    return View(track_info.ToList().GroupBy(x => x.collegeOf).Select(y => y.First()));
}
```

Reference can be found [here](http://abundantcode.com/how-to-remove-duplicates-and-get-distinct-records-from-list-using-linq/).